# How to parse AST openMP with clang

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm, openmp

I'm so new for compilers and currently started clang. I would like to parse openmp pragma lines with clang and my question is is it possible? in fact i saw lots of presentation about supporting openmp however i couldn't find any example about how to parse? if you have or know useful example, could you send me?

thanks lot

Comment: Current versions of `clang` do not support OpenMP.

Comment: @HristoIliev really?uh, I don't know. But i saw lots of code pieces about openmp in the clang. if so, can i still parse with some clang-plugin that you recommend?

Comment: Intel is trying to marry `clang` and the newly open-sourced Intel OpenMP runtime: see [here](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2013-04/#talk2). There are also other projects that are developing OpenMP-enabled LLVM compilers. Unfortunately I am not a user of `clang` and cannot recommend you such a front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found finally. Currently Clang only supports omp parallel directive, moreover almost without clause :)

in order to use it, i used these parameters:

```
clang -Xclang -ast-dump -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp yoursourcefile.c
```

and i could see omp statement in the ast.

```
OMPParallelDirective 0xd09a09c <line:6:13, col:25>
-CapturedStmt 0xd09a088 <line:7:5, col:18>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Polly](http://polly.llvm.org/). It supports OpenMP and is based on llvm. Polly generates LLVM IR annotated with GOMP library calls and it is easy to write your own pass to get a handle on these calls.

If you really need the pragma information in the frontend, you will need to dig into the code to get a handle on the pragmas. In any case you do not need to write your own parser.

Detailed information about how Polly handles OpenMP pragmas can be found in this [document](http://polly.llvm.org/publications/raghesh-a-masters-thesis.pdf).